# Tensorflow Lite model maker: training chart possible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

i am using the Tensorflow Lite Model Maker library to train an efficient model for object detection. It works well, but I don’t know how to get graphs of the training process.
It prints just the loss values per epoch on the console.
Is it possible to get a chart with for example accuracy, recall, precision, f1,…(for every epoch) while or after training?
Such a chart would be great for my master’s thesis. Thank you so much.

Greetings,

Daniel Hauser

Answer (score 1):

Late :) .. i hope to help any one else

you can use Tensorpoard:

```
tensorboard --logdir training_events_path
```

to find Training event path:

When you start the training, the Tensorflow Lite Model Maker library create temp folder to save training files.

I found it on C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvu_xi7e7

the folder name will be different but start with tmp...

go to the URL that will be showed after run trnsorboard on cmd.

example:
TensorBoard 2.9.0 at http://localhost:6006/

you should see the graphs of your training process under Scalars.

Answer (score -1):

when you do ***model.train(...)*** the function return history json object

```
history = model.train(...)
```

you can list all data in history

```
print(history.history.keys())
```

To plot the history accuracy:

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: accuracy]

history for loss

```
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: loss]